# Without back up info and unable to receive verification code,, how can I access my Google account

Tags: gmail, password

I cannot access my Google account because I lost my back up info and I cannot receive a verification code, because I no longer have access to my old phone. How can I get into my Google account?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Account Recovery](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/recoveryidentifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AccountRecovery).  It will ask you some questions.

The complete process is [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7682439?hl=en)

> **Forgot your password**
>
> 1. Follow the steps to recover your Google Account or Gmail. [Recovery](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/recoveryidentifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AccountRecovery)
>
>    - You'll be asked some questions to confirm it's your account. Answer the questions as best as you can.
>    - If you have trouble, try the tips to complete account recovery steps.
> 2. Reset your password when prompted. Choose a strong password that you haven't already used with this account. Learn how to create a strong password.

If that doesn't work, then the help suggests that you create a new account.  And this time, give it your phone number for recovery.